# Align columns output c++

Tags: c++, output

I want read a file where there are the names of AC Milan's players and their date of birth. I want display this in two aligned columns. I tried to use setw() and left but the result isn't what I want. This is the code that I used for read and print:

```
void read(char filename[]){
    fstream mio_file;
    char c;
    bool start_name = true;
    bool start_date = true;

    mio_file.open(filename, ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);

    mio_file.read(&c, sizeof(char));
    while(!mio_file.eof()){

        if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'z' && start_name){
            cout << endl << "Name : ";
            start_name = false;
            start_date = true;
        }
        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9' && start_date){
            cout << setw(25) << left << "Date of birth : ";
            start_date = false;
            start_name = true;
        }

        cout << c;
        mio_file.read(&c, sizeof(char));
    }

    mio_file.close();
}
```

This is output :

[image]

And this is output that I want :

[image]

Comment: setw(...) for name

Comment: @RickAstley: It's used correctly here. Treat this as a lesson in making sweeping statements!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) for each of the *columns*. Not just set it once. Example:

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "Column 1" << std::setw(25) << "Column 2" << std::endl;
```

In your particular case you only need to apply it on the *Name* column:

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(25) << "Name : ";
```

Comment: It's not needed on any other column but the name.

Comment: I tried add setw + left first of "Name : " string but the effect is that of shift to right the player's name.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I stand corrected. I tried to give a more general answer. I have updated the answer as per your input.

Comment: @Ron Your solution doesn't work. The result is "Name : AxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbateDateofBirth : 12/11/1986" x is the space. Note that the first lettert is capital

Answer (score 1):

*(N.B. I'm guessing at your input data, which you did not provide.*)

You put `setw` in the wrong place.

It goes before the thing you're columnising, not afterwards. (This is because the manipulator needs to start counting characters in order to make it work.)

So, instead of ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/202e523f4b412767)):

```
cout << setw(25) << left << "Date of birth : ";
```

try ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/906c30eb036abc4c)):

```
cout << endl << "Name : " << setw(25) << left;
```

Now the stream is set up to treat the next insertion (i.e your. `cout << c`) as columnar, left-aligned with width 25.

Unfortunately, you're reading individual characters at a time, so your IO manipulator is never going to work on the full name; only individual characters.

So you're also going to have to do some buffering before you feed `cout` with full strings ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a7b88b8a58b5a70)):

```
std::string token;
mio_file.read(&c, sizeof(char));
while(!mio_file.eof()){

    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'z' && start_name) {
        cout << token;
        cout << endl << "Name : " << setw(25) << left;
        token = "";
        start_name = false;
        start_date = true;
    }
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9' && start_date) {
        cout << token;
        cout << "Date of birth : ";
        token = "";
        start_date = false;
        start_name = true;
    }

    token += c;
    mio_file.read(&c, sizeof(char));
}

// Final write
cout << token;
```

I'm sure there's a better way of implementing this loop, though.

Comment: if I change how you say the result is for first name : "Name : AxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbateDateofBirth : 12/11/1986" x is the space

Comment: It only works with strings?  If I want read only a char there isn't solution?

Comment: @Chuck94: There you go

Comment: @Chuck94: Of course it "only works with strings"; otherwise how does the stream know how many inputs you want to count as part of the column?